# Ngrok fails to serve PHP session cookie:

Tags: php, session-cookies, ngrok

I use ngrok to tunnel localhost to a web address

```
./ngrok http 80
```

I use only custom PHP code. Last time I tested it was working ok. Now, I can't login because it seems my PHP resets the data stored in session every 5 or so requests.

When I say `reset` I mean that my code calls [session_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) **does not** get it and resets that valuable session data including internal captcha code! At the end captcha comparison fails!

Everything works fine at `localhost` though!

I reset [session.cookie_domain](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain)  with [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) setting the `ngrok` url.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

At last I found it: for a address `xxx.ngrok.io` just set php [session cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) for domain `.xxx.ngrok.io` and do **not** include `http`.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for ngrok cookie issue.

Comment: Not working on subdomains for me. Tried .ngrok-free.app without success. It works only if I set the full domain + subdomain.